# javascript functional programming External Dependence mutation

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Can someone explain this javascript behavior?

```
let a = {z: true};
console.log(a);
const modify = obj => {
  let b = {
    a: "hello",
    b: 22
  }
  obj = {...obj, ...b}
  return obj;
}
modify(a);
console.log(modify(a))
```

**output:**

```
{
  z:true,
  a:"hello",
  b:22
}
```

is obj in `obj = {...obj, ...b}` an implicitly new created object or is this the same `obj` parameter of `modify`.
because when I try to comment the `return obj;` line (`//return obj;`) in a visual studio text editor the parameter `obj` inside the `modify` function seems to be faded meaning that I'm not using it inside the function. Also without having to `return obj;` i just wanted to alter a given object and bind to it some new properties. is this possible?

Comment: This question needs to describe a lot about objects. You should understand javascript types (primitive and reference type), also check how the `spread` operator works for merging two objects. In short, if you pass an object to a function and modifying it inside that function then you are modifying the passed object and hence `return` is not necessary. Also, your functional approach is wrong because in functional programming, you should not have side effects and you are doing it, it's not a pure function. That's all for now.

Comment: @TheAlpha yes you're right. we shouldn't call it a function approach :XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object in your code is not mutated. The object literal notation (with `{ }`) always *creates* an object. Secondly, the assignment to `obj` is to the local variable with that name, not the variable of the caller (`a`). To mutate the given object, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
let a = {z: true};
console.log(a);
const modify = obj => {
  let b = {
    a: "hello",
    b: 22
  }
  // The return is not absolutely necessary...
  return Object.assign(obj, b);
}
modify(a);
console.log(a);
```

Of course, when you let functions mutate objects, you are no longer in line with *functional programming* principles.

Answer (score 1):

`obj = {...obj, ...b}` will create a new object.
If you want to change the given object just change his properties:

```
   const modify = obj => {
       obj.a = "hello"
       obj.b = 22
    }
```

If you want to combine new object to your existsing object you can also use `Object.assign`:

`Object.assign(obj, b)`

Comment: I find that quite *explicit* object creation.

Comment: @arielhad what if I had 50 properties? should i have to write obj. property all the time? now i was thinking of spreading a new object right inside of the given object and of course without overwriting it